# How to link a css file and a html file for a django website template?

Tags: html, css, django, web, figma

I have a css code and a html file exported from my figma design templates. Idk if I want to combine this css and html to have them in my django website. I'm not someone who knows anything about css plus just a bit of html, I'm learning python. Please let me know if I should do any additional work.

Comment: Haha, I'll try learning it in future

Comment: This question is opinion-based and should not be asked on StackOverflow

Answer (score 1):

To use HTML and CSS files in a django project, you need to put the css file in the `static\` folder of your django project and move your HTML file into the `templates\` folder. Then link your CSS file to your HTML file using the following code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/<css_file_name>.css' %}">
```

* Replace `<css_file_name>` with your CSS file's name